# How to filter by two columns in a single table that both point to another table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

How do you set up a data model in Power BI when one table has several columns that point to a single other table? For example, I have a sessions table that includes columns like "providerID", "created_by", "modified_by", "co_signID", etc and they all point back to the provider details table which contains the matching ID and "ProviderName". However, I can't connect all four columns to that same providers table at the same time. If I want to see or filter by a specific provider, with a specific co-signer, it wouldn't be possible to do so in one Power BI dashboard. At least I don't think so. Does anyone know of a way to do this? Is there a way to "point" a filter through a specific ID or is the answer in the way the data is modelled?

The only solution that I know of forces me to overwrite the ids with the actual names which is not efficient storage and it's certainly not a good data modeling practice (you'd have to continuously overwrite that column to make sure it stays accurate). Is there a better way to do this?